# Solr - WordDelimiterFactory with Custom Tokenizer to split only on Boundires

Tags: solr

I have configured WordDelimiterFilterFactory for custom tokenizers for `&` and `-` which is working fine.

And for few tokenizer (like `.` `_` `:`) we need to split on boundries only. And not to split if in between of word.

e.g.

```
test.com (should tokenized to test.com)
newyear. coming (should tokenized to newyear and coming)
new_car (should tokenized to new_car)
..
..
```

I checked that types can be used in `Solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` are `LOWER`, `UPPER`, `ALPHA`, `DIGIT`, `ALPHANUM`, `SUBWORD_DELIM` . there's no description available for use of each type. as per name suggest , i thought type SUBWORD_DELIM may fulfill my need, but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is defination for text field

```
<fieldType name="text_general_preserved" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false" />
         <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                splitOnCaseChange ="0"
                splitOnNumerics ="0"
                stemEnglishPossessive ="0"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="0"
                protected="protwords_general.txt"
                types="wdfftypes_general.txt"
                />

        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                splitOnCaseChange ="0"
                splitOnNumerics ="0"
                stemEnglishPossessive ="0"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="0"
                protected="protwords_general.txt"
                types="wdfftypes_general.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

below is wdfftypes_general.txt content

```
& => ALPHA
- => ALPHA
_ => SUBWORD_DELIM
: => SUBWORD_DELIM
. => SUBWORD_DELIM
```

Can anybody suggest me how can i set configuration for `Solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` to fulfill my requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation for [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html), the SUBOWRD_DELIM settings in the wdfftypes.txt file only impact the behavior based on the splitOnCaseChange and splitOnNumerics settings. Therefore, I would add `:` `_` `.` as ALPHA entries in the wdfftypes.txt file and add a new [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory) after the WordDelimiterFilterFactory in your fieldType to remove those leading or trailing character from any tokens.